# Google Chrome - Dev Tool - Network Tab: Design update

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

How can I revert the recent update to the "Request Types" design in the Dev tool and restore it to the previous version?

[image]

I updated Chrome, and now the design of the request types in the network tab of the DevTools has changed to a dropdown list.

Comment: Accidentally made a duplicate of your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77939638/chrome-devtools-groups-the-network-tabs-filters-pane and I got the same answer =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can disable it in settings -> Experiments:

[image: screenshot of setting panel]