# Chrome DevTools groups the Network tab's filters pane

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

After a recent Chrome update (currently running Version 121.0.6167.140 (Official Build) (64-bit)), the Network tab now groups the requests in a select:
[image: devtools-new-filters]

and they used to be as tabs, [for example](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference#filter):
[image: devtools-old-filters]

Does anyone know how can I return back to the tabular structure, instead of the select one?

Since I cannot go back to an older Chrome version, it would be nice if there's a way to actually revert only that change and have the filters not selectable, but viewed all at glance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to DevTools > Settings > Experiments and disable "Redesign of the filter in the Network Panel". Re-open DevTools.

[DevTools > Settings > Experiments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D00TC.png)

Comment: Much appreciated! Here's an image for all those who are lost like I was: https://i.imgur.com/IMME8Lt.png